# Order status of shopping cart. (Opencart)

Tags: magento, paypal, opencart, shopping-cart

What are the status meaning? I have googled a lot, but didn't find a full explanation.

Opencart has many status, these are mostly used:
1 Pending
2 Processing
5 Complete
15 Processed
3 Shipped

I guess:

**Pending**
Waiting for customer to confirm. No any action for payment.

**Processing**
Customer has started to pay. I have a payment module in my country, lets call it "ecpay". When the customer choose the payment, then choose ATM(or Credit card), click continue, then ecpay add an order history, change the order status to "Processing", and provide the website's bank account to customer. (Now customer has a bank account.)

**Complete**
Maybe one or three days later, the customer pays, , the "ecpay" will send some information through api, change the order status to be 5.

**Shipped**
When the products are shipped, administrators go to admin, change status to be this.

So, "Complete" does not actually mean the order is totally complete, just mean that the payment is complete. If every thing runs well, "Shipped" is the final status. Is it right?  By the way, the payment module ecpay doesn't use "Pending".

When to use Pending? and Processed? Where can I find all the status meanings of an order.

Answer (score 0):

In **Magento** :

***Pending:*** Pending orders are brand new orders that have not been processed. Typically, these orders need to be invoiced and shipped. You can use pending status before invoice is generated.

***Processing:*** Processing means that orders have either been invoiced or shipped, but not both.

For More Detail : [***Magento Order Statuses***](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/516)

In **OpenCart** :

***Pending:*** When an order is made its status might be pending.

***Processing:*** Once the payment has been confirmed the status might be set to processing.

For More Detail : [***Open Cart Statuses***](https://sites.google.com/a/kevronent.com/opencart-documentation-user-guide/documentation/localisation/order-statuses)

Answer (score 0):

`Pending - When an order is made its status might be pending.
Processing - Once the payment has been confirmed the status might be set to processing.
Shipped - When the order is shipped it can be set to shipped.
Complete - If the order has arrived at its destination it can be set to complete.
Refunded - If the order is returned and refunded it should be set to refunded.
Canceled - If for what ever reason the order is canceled before being shipped the status could be set to canceled.`

Order status can be changed by admin